# 404 error serving .js files on ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I've got a straightforward ASP.NET Core web app using Razor pages (not MVC). I've been looking at the Application Insights as I run the app and see a ton of 404 errors related to files like this...

`https://localhost:5001/~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js`

My Startup class has `app.UseStaticFiles();` and is able to serve other files in the root directory and sub directories like `css` and `images`. So why can't it find and serve these `.js` files? I've tried adding options to the static file configuration but nothing seems to work. I keep getting the 404 errors in Application Insights. I can go to the file explorer and see that these files all exist. I've been working on this for hours with no success.

Comment: What happens when you remove `~` part from that URL?

Comment: Weird. I just created a new web app from the template and it doesn't generate those 404 errors. the rquest paths are like `/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js`. So maybe the problem does have to do with that ~ character. I'm not sure where that is coming from. I didn't mess with master page that links to those bootstrap files.

Comment: the _Layout.cshtml files between my project and the basic template are nearly identical. Both use the ~ character in the paths to the js files. The Startup.cs files are nearly the same too. I'm not sure what is different between my app and the empty template that is causing these 404 errors.

Comment: I replaced the entire _Layout.cshtml file in my project with the one from the basic template - same 404 error. Both projects using asp.net core 2.2.

Comment: Very weird. When I take the `~` characters out of the paths in my layout.cshtml file everything works with no 404 errors. BUT the empty site template from Microsoft includes these characters and it works just fine. I'm hesitant to take out the tilde characters from my layout.cshtml since I assume they are there for a good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~` should be changed to the root of the application (which might be the root of the domain, or a virtual directory). If it's not, then it's not being used correctly.

My guess is that you have a slash in front:

```
<script src="/~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

The path should begin with a `~`, not a slash:

```
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes the problem was with the `~` characters in the path. But the question was how the paths got so screwed up especially since my Layout.cshtml file was identical to the one in the sample asp.net core project. The answer had to do with the fact that I required a `th:` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My clue was that in the empty template project in the Layout.cshtml some of the tags like `<environment>` were displayed in bold but in my project they weren't. In my `ViewImports` file I included `@tagHelperPrefix th:` which makes it so the Microsoft tag helpers require special syntax like `<th:link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />`. The Microsoft tag helpers must do something special with paths that involve a `~` character.

When I replaced all my link tags in Layout.cshtml from `<link>` to `<th:link>` it started to work. Or I can take out `@tagHelperPrefix th:` from ViewImports and use the normal looking tags.